# SQL Full Text Contains not returning expected rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I have a `Body` column that is full text indexed and is `nvarchar(max)`

One row has this in the `Body` column

`You want slighty mad this sat the 60th runing of the 3peaks race! Peny-ghent whernside and inglbauher! Only in yorkshire!`

If I run: `select body from messages where CONTAINS(Body,'you')` it doesn't return any data.

If I run the below adding wildcards `select messageid,body from messages where CONTAINS(body,'"*you*"')` it still doesnt return the data.

Can you help me understand what's going on please?

Thanks

**UPDATE :** It makes no difference if its `you` or `You`, either way no results

Comment: That should work fine.  Have you triple checked everything in the chain to make sure that you should be getting results?  Aka - querying the right db, table actually contains the expected results, etc.

Comment: yes cause the thats where i've picked the example above from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full text catalog has a set of words in a “stoplist” that it won’t search on as SQL Server considers them “unimportant for search purposes”

To get this you can run

```
select ssw.*
  from sys.fulltext_system_stopwords ssw
  where ssw.language_id = 1033;
```

Below are the words it won’t search on and you’ll see it contains “you” hence why it didn’t find my data.

Answer (score 0):

It can be case sensitivity issue. Try with `select messageid,body from messages where CONTAINS(body,'"*You*"')` and see if you are getting the result or not

Comment: Is like is working if used instead on CONTAINS ??.. For e.g. `select messageid,body from messages where body like '%You%'`